# Rails routes - add more scope with same routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails app with a routes.rb file defined in it. In the routes file, the content is like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/v1' do
    ...
    post 'sign-up',                    to: 'registration#create'
    get 'messages-counterparts',       to: 'messages#messages_counterparts', as: :messages_counterparts
    ...
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is to add a scope for `v2` with the same content of `v1` , where I am going to change things step by step.

I tried to put another scope and add the copy and past of the code, but it gives error on any of the path with `as:`.

I would like to know how can I reach my goal and the best practises to do it. I tried to google with no luck.

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Two routes cannot have the same name. Use a different name for the `/v2/messages-counterparts` route.

```rb
scope '/v2' do
  # ...
  get 'messages-counterparts',
      to: 'messages#messages_counterparts',
      as: :v2_messages_counterparts
end
```

Comment: ok, so the only way is to modify all my previous routes with 'as:' to new url, right? There is no chance to avoid it? Thanks for the response

Comment: @emish89 Yeah, you have to update the old route names to fix the issue.